# QGIS Desktop not installing

Tags: qgis-3, installation, osgeo4w, windows-10

I am trying to install the QGIS Desktop application on Windows 10.

Upon a successful install, only the OSGeo4W Shell and the Grass GIS 7.8.5 are there on the apps list (within the QGIS folder), the actual QGIS Desktop app is not there.

I get the .exe file from the regular qggis dot come downloads website ("QGIS-OSGeo4W-3.16.5-1-Setup-x86_64").

I've tried with both the 64-bit standalone installers for 3.16 Hanover and (latest) 3.18 Zurich version. This process has worked just fine in the past.

My computer's virus protection program Sophos Endpoint Agent keeps detecting and clearing a file named nircmd.exe from the QGIS/3.1x/bin folder, wondering if that has anything to do with it (says "Threats cleaned up. NirCmd detected at file path..."). I don't know what I'm doing wrong now or what is missing. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

**Run OSGeo4W** - this will open a terminal.

Type qgis in that terminal end hit Enter.

If you don't see 'qgis', try 'qgis-grass7' etc.

Comment: I typed qgis in the OSGeo4W Shell terminal and it returns: "'qgis' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."

Comment: type o-help >temp.txt in the same window. I guess 'qgis' is not in the list of executables?

Comment: Actually, installing OSGeo4W should install qgis for you. Are you installing some other way?

Comment: I am only doing a regular install, ran the executable files named QGIS-OSGeo4W-3.16.5-1-Setup-x86_64.exe and QGIS-OSGeo4W-3.18.1-1-Setup-x86_64.exe downloaded from https://qgis.org/en/site/forusers/download.html

Comment: Okay, the o-help >temp.txt produced results. I found that the command qgis-grass7 works, it opens QGIS Desktop. And now the QGIS3 App appeared under the QGIS folders

Comment: No need to install separately. You may be confusing the system! Select the Express Desktop Installation and make sure QGIS is checked.

Comment: RE: "... I found that the command qgis-grass7 works, it opens QGIS Desktop. And now the QGIS3 App appeared under the QGIS folders" - I don't know what that does or why, but I'm glad it works! I use Mac but only sometimes Win10, so my knowledge is limited. Maybe someone can explain it. I'll include it in the answer as an option.

Comment: I am having the same issue as the OP and I have tried the fix above and it doesn't appear to work.